# Xamarin.Forms ListView with Selectable Items and Checkbox-Like Functionality

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project, and I need to implement a ListView with selectable items, each having a checkbox-like functionality using a Switch. I have a custom data model (YourItemModel) representing each item with a Name and IsChecked property.

Here's a simplified version of my XAML:

```
<!-- YourPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.YourPage">

    <ListView x:Name="menuListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemSelected="MenuListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

And the corresponding code-behind:

```
// YourPage.xaml.cs

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace

{

    public partial class YourPage : ContentPage

    {

        public ObservableCollection<YourItemModel> Items { get; set; }

        public YourPage()

        {

            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new ObservableCollection<YourItemModel>

            {

                new YourItemModel { Name = "Option 1", IsChecked = false },

                new YourItemModel { Name = "Option 2", IsChecked = true },

                new YourItemModel { Name = "Option 3", IsChecked = false }

            };

            menuListView.ItemsSource = Items;

        }

        private void MenuListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)

        {

            if (e.SelectedItem == null)

                return;

            var selectedItem = (YourItemModel)e.SelectedItem;

            DisplayAlert("Item Selected", $"{selectedItem.Name} is checked: {selectedItem.IsChecked}", "OK");

            // Reset the selected item to null to allow deselection

            menuListView.SelectedItem = null;

        }

    }


}
```

I'm looking for guidance on improving the checkbox-like functionality, handling the selection, and any best practices or tips for implementing such a feature in Xamarin.Forms. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pleas read [ask] before posting.  As written your question is off-topic

Comment: Not quite understand. Since Xamarin has [Checkbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/checkbox), then why you use a Switch or other checkbox-like control?

Comment: Do you mean set the ```IsChecked`` property when the corresponding item is selected?